# Form over $ \mathbb{Z} $ of non-split simple algebraic groups over non-archimedean local fields

Tags: algebraic-groups

Here is a basic observation :

On page 68 of his article *Reductive groups over local fields*, Jacques Tits writes:

> All types of groups listed (...) exist over an arbitrary [non-archimedean local] field (...). The central isogeny class corresponding to a given name is always unique except in the following cases. (...)

Let us ignore those exceptions, and assume that we are given a type, say $ t $, whose isogeny class over any non-archimedean local field is unique. Then the situation is reminiscent of the split situation, where for any given type, one proves the existence and uniqueness (up to isogeny) of this type of split groups over any field.

This motivates the following question:

Let $ t $ be a type of algebraic group as in the previous paragraph. Does there exist an algebraic group defined over $ \mathbb{Q} $ whose base change to $ k $ is of type $ t $, for all non-archimedean local field $ k $ of characteristic $0$ ?

(see grghxy comments why we restrict to char. $0$ and why we then can use $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$).

EDIT : I edited the question to take into account all comments of grghxy.

Note that so far, the only given obstruction comes from a non-trivial Galois action on the Dynkin diagram. But looking at the classification, one can see that if the Galois action is non-trivial, then the type of algebraic group has more than one isogeny class (and the converse is true except for the form $SL_n (D)$).

So, the question remains : for types that have a unique isogeny class, is there any obstruction to being defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Here is the list of such non-split types. They are in fact uniquely determined by their Tits index $X_{n,r}$ (where $X_n$ is the absolute type, and $r$ the relative rank):
$B_{n,n-1}$, $C_{2n-1,n-1}$, $C_{2n,n}$, $D_{2n+1,n-1}$, $E_{6,2}$, $E_{7,4}$

Comment: No. You must assume $k$ of characteristic 0 (or else the answer is clearly "no"), and then it is unclear what you mean by "algebraic group over $\mathbf{Z}$"; cannot mean "reductive" (groups not split over an unramified extension are counterexamples), but for "smooth affine group" the content is descent to $\mathbf{Q}$ (group-smoothening does the rest). The splitting field of the Galois action on the diagram is then an obstruction, if it doesn't arise from a Galois extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ (e.g., take a unitary group over $k$ that contains all quadratic extensions of some $\mathbf{Q}_p$).

Comment: @grgxy You are awesome, as usual (if my guess of who you are is correct) ! Could you please expand on how you prove your assertions (clearly no in pos. char. and if G has to be reductive over Z). And unfortunately, I cannot make sense now of what is _the splitting field_ (of the Galois action on the diagram), and what does it mean that it arises from a Galois extension (but I will try to see what happens on your specific last example). Any other hint would be appreciated, or any pointer to related literature.

Comment: Well, I meant @grghxy ...

Comment: If $G$ descends to $\mathbf{Z}$ with $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ then $G$ descends to $\mathbf{F}_p$ and so is quasi-split. If $G$ admits a reductive $\mathbf{Z}$-model (with connected fibers) then it extends to a reductive group (with connected fibers) over the valuation ring of $k$. But any reductive group scheme (with connected fibers) over a complete local noetherian ring with quasi-split reduction (e.g., finite residue field) is itself quasi-split due to smoothness of the scheme of Borel subgroups. Thus, $G$ that are not quasi-split are counterexamples of the sort I had in mind.

Comment: As for the comment about Dynkin diagrams, Tits has a notion of "$\ast$-action" of the absolute Galois group on the diagram; it keeps track of the inner-twisting class (trivial action for the quasi-split forms).  In SGA3 this is developed more elegantly in terms of the notion of "scheme of Dynkin diagrams" which is not as widely known is it deserves to be (but upon unraveling really is Tits' construction in another guise).  For unitary groups in $\ge 3$ variables this corresponds to the "associated" quadratic Galois extension (with action on type-A diagram through the diagram involution).